# Use [NotMapped] on an attribute coming from a parent class in entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, data-annotations

I have a Master base Class like this.

```
    public class MasterTemplate
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Code { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(255)]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public decimal? SortOrder { get; set; }
    }
```

I have many classes that inherit the above class.
For example, Caste, Nationality, Currency, etc..,

```
    public class Nationality : MasterTemplate
    {

        // Other memebers of nationality
    }

    public class Caste: MasterTemplate
    {

        // Other memebers of caste
    }
```

Most of the classes need all the columns, but some of my classes do not need "Description", some of them do not need "Code", some other do not need "SortOrder".

```
    public class Zone: MasterTemplate
    {
        // Logic to mark Description [NotMapped], 
        // so that EF doesn't create a column in database

        // Other memebers of zone
    }
```

For a member in same class I can use [NotMapped], but how do I do this from a child class for a parent class attribute. I know I can remove inheritance and do it, but curious to know if there is any possibility to do this from child class for a parent class attribute.

Edit:

As sugested by @IvanJazz, modified the code as follows.

```
public class MasterTemplate
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public virtual string Code { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual decimal? SortOrder { get; set; }
}

public class Nationality : MasterTemplate
{
    // Code will not appear in Nationality table
    [NotMapped]
    public override string Code { get; set; }
}

public class Zone : MasterTemplate
{
    // Description will not appear in Zone table
    [NotMapped]
    public override string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Now logically, entity framework shouldn't search for the overrided and marked as NotMapped attributes while adding a record. While inserting following DbValidation error occurs. Not sure why entity framework still searching for notmapped attributes.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If some of your classes don't need some inherited properties then they shouldn't be in the baseclass to begin with ;-)

Comment: Yup, I am using inheritence here for only convenience, i know it's not right, don't want to create multiple base classes, if here is no other way, will remove inheritence here.

Comment: Is there any reason that prevents you from using fluent api?

Comment: Nope, I can use it, only trying to find other options. Also I wanted to know, after the migration is generated, can I directly remove the column from there, or make it nullable true? Will it create any problem?

Answer (score 3):

you could use the `virtual` and `override` modifiers to achieve your desired results. Mark all optional properties as `virtual` and `override` them in your derived class with the `[NotMapped]` attribute.

```
public class MasterTemplate
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public virtual string Code { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual decimal? SortOrder { get; set; }
}

public class Nationality : MasterTemplate
{
    // Code will not appear in Nationality table
    [NotMapped]
    public override string Code { get; set; }
}

public class Zone : MasterTemplate
{
    // Description will not appear in Zone table
    [NotMapped]
    public override string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: While IvanJazz answer is correct for your question, it's worth noting that having properties in a base class that not all the sub classes use can lead to messy and unpredictable code.
You might want to consider a base class with all the shared columns, and further abstract intermediates to ensure that any instance of a specific abstract only contains columns it actually implements.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. @kristian williams, Thank you for the suggestion, I am sure my boss will not agree to do something like this, will apply this logic in very rare cases.

Comment: When EF tries to add a record, it throws an exception saying that "Description" feild is required, I declared a Constructor in my "Zone" class and assigned blank string to description, still the error occurs, I think here entity framework is expecting Description feild, how do we solve this?

Comment: @PrasanthKumarVinakota Weird, considering the `Description` property is overriden in `Zone` class with the `NotMapped` attribute, it cannot be required anymore. You won't even have to set description to anything, in the eyes of EF at this point, your `Description` property is non-existent in the `Zone` table.

Comment: Yaa true, but during adding record, it says Description feild is required. please find attached screenshots.

Comment: Just initialise the `Description` field to something like say "Undefined", not empty string in your default constructor. It won't matter to your database.